# Implementing the "Go to Home" functionality in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to implement a Home button in my Android App which will terminate the all the Activities but the first one. Instead of user pressing the Back button again and again, I want to give user a single button which will take him/her on the first (Home) Activity.
Please help how to implement it.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776830/android-moving-back-to-first-activity-on-button-click

Answer (score 2):

I dont have the SDK on this laptop to be sure about the syntax, but i think this is it.

Set up a listener for the "home" button, in the onClick() method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityYouAreOnNow.this,firstActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```