# Resuming Home Screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I navigate to the subsequent activities in my project and from one activity i want to come at the home screen...Please suggest the exact code for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to launch an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with action set to ACTION_MAIN and a category of CATEGORY_HOME.

Something along the lines of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is taking me to the Home screen of the device...i want to move back to home screen to the application...Please advise on it...Similar to popviewcontroller we have in iphone

Comment: @devaditya - then I think you should make your question clearer. "Home Screen" is the home screen of the device. If you mean something else then you should make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Check this old answer: [Android moving back to first activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776830/android-moving-back-to-first-activity-on-button-click)