# How to go to previous activity?

Tags: android

This code does not go to previous activity, when button is click should do: current activity to another acitivity. If i write  finish(); works fine, but what is wrong in my code? In my 3rd activity `AgAppAskPinForTransaction`  when I press back button does not go to `agappmenu.class`(Previous Activity). What is wrong in this code? How to go to previous activity? I do not want to use "`finish();`"  I just want to close current activity and go to previous activity when button clicked?

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity  {


       Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AgAppMenu.class);


         MyBean bean = new MyBean();
         bean.set2DArray(xmlRespone);
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("mybean", bean);
            i.putExtra("obj", b);
            startActivity(i);





              public class AgAppMenu extends Activity {




            Intent intent = new Intent(AgAppMenu.this,  
   AgAppAskPinForTransaction.class);

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("mno", "MIN");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
   }






         public class AgAppAskPinForTransaction extends Activity{




             btngoback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)

{
Intent intent = new Intent(AgAppMenu.this,          
     AgAppAskPinForTransaction.class);
    startActivity(intent);



      }

                                });
```

Comment: my question is how to go previous activity withour using  finish();

Comment: `finish();` Closes the current activity and goes back to the last one. Why you want to do it another way, is pointless. You can call new activities using Intent. But they will new instances of previous activities.

Comment: [this may helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776830/android-moving-back-to-first-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActvitiy(i);
```

Edit:
put this in activity 3

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed () 
{
     startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
}
```

Comment: but u didnot mention from which acitvity to which activity in this code

Comment: i want to go this code when i click

public void onClick(View v)
 
 {
 Intent intent = new Intent(AgAppMenu.this,          
         AgAppAskPinForTransaction.class);
        startActivity(intent);


 
          }

                                 });

Comment: getIntent() gets the intent from this activity, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should send you back one activity

Comment: no i dont want jest previous activity suppose i go activity1-->activity2   activity2--> activity3 activity3--> activity1

then how is work??

Comment: tell me please how its possible??

Comment: override onBackPressed in this funciton to start activity 1

Comment: also you could call .popBackStack() in activity 2

Comment: ur code only go previous activity how do i go 1st activity when click back button in activity 3??

Comment: i didnot understand give me example please  ur last code which u give me above is not work i try it nts no o anywhere

Comment: how to add backpress method inside button click listener?

Answer (score 0):

try to start your previous activity like

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyFourActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActvitiy(i);
```

and to read the new `Intent` you sent
 override 
`onNewIntent` method on `AppMenu Activity`

Comment: is only fonr previous acitivty imean last visited activity suppose i wan to go 1st activity after reach 4th then what would i do?

Comment: dnt want finish is only go previous not targerted activity