# android how to go previous visited activity when press button

Tags: android

how to go previous activity after going like this  previous activity suppose i go activity1-->activity2 activity2--> activity3 activity3--> activity1 then how is work?? 
when i press button hwo is go back to activity1? i  use this but its not work tell me how to go previous visited activity?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity4.this, Activity1.class);

startActivity(intent);


   i also use this code is not work for me
  Intent i = getIntent();
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);

   //finish();    finish just previous acitivity is not work for me
```

Comment: [this may helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776830/android-moving-back-to-first-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: ur link not work for me i try it

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the implementation looks this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity1.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will kill all `Activities` above `Activity1` and throw you back to it. Hope this helps.

Comment: @HayyaAnam, Application what?

Comment: imean application stop unwxpectedly

Comment: @HayyaAnam, Then you should post the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:launchMode="singleTask" attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    activity android:name=".Activity1" android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

This is very important. If you don't add that attribute, your activity will always be re-created on each intent and it's state will be re-initialized. That's why you receive an error message and your application crashes.

Then Use following code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity1.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set true on the manifest to noHistory on the activity 2.
no extra code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks It is working

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity1.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```