# Android: go back to activity, after using intent with sms

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

First of all, [link to the project](https://github.com/studentizer/Studentizer) and ling to the [used fragment](https://github.com/studentizer/Studentizer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/edu/ug/aib/studentizerApp/fragment/TimetableFragment.java) and [used activity](https://github.com/studentizer/Studentizer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/edu/ug/aib/studentizerApp/DrawerActivity.java). I've got a problem with going back to the DrawerActivity, after using intent for sending a sms. I'm launching the intent from the `TimetableFragment` in the listview `onItemLongClick` listener and then it's going do use the method `sendSms` in the `DrawerActivity`

```
listTrainLeftLstView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
               @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //selected stations
                    String stationFrom = startIdSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String stationTo = endIdSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    //selected item
                    Train selectedItem = (Train) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    String selectedTime = selectedItem.hour + ":" + selectedItem.minute;
                    String direction = selectedItem.tip;

                    //send sms (communication fragment -> activity)
                   mCallback.sendSms("heheszki");

                    return true;
               }
            });
```

It works, I can send the sms, but after sending it don't go back to the `DrawerActivity` - it still sits in the sms intent. Also if I use the back button it's going to close my app.

Implementing solution with `onCreate` method is going to crash my app at the start, and using `onActivityResult` is going to pass:

```
resultCode = 0
```

The expected result is to go back to `DrawerActivity` after sending the sms, and go back to the `DrawerActivity` while pressing Back button in the sms intent.

Comment: Any knowledge how to get back to my app from sms app?

Answer (score 1):

Once to switch to another activity the previous activity will be cleared from the stack.try finish() so that it gets back to previous activity.

Comment: Where I should put that finish()? In the code for starting the intent with SMS? I tried that, but didn't work out well...

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776830/android-moving-back-to-first-activity-on-button-click)